# Why does animating my Character deform the Mesh?

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers

I used the skin modifier over some connected vertices to create a character.

After animating it, this is my result:

[image: deformation]

Why is the root/pelvis part deforming the skin? I pretty much use default settings in everything, not sure why this happens out of the box.

Comment: Maybe too low topology for it to actually have a good chance to deform properly? Is the weight paint set correctly?

Comment: im sorry but i have no idea. topology? weight paint? i saw weight paint option but when i go into it i dont see much

Comment: Oh OK. So topology is what we refer when we talk about the quads/tris/n-gons of a mesh. The  weight paint is used for many things, particle destribution, mesh deform, but here you can use it with an armature to deside what bone affects which area how much...  If you have a high topology you can have more details in it and so you can deform the mesh more precisely.

Comment: i am getting very weird results with weight paint.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos for example after messing with weight paints i cant move the bones anymore and when i pull onlythe black thing moves https://i.imgur.com/Waf1LBI.png

Comment: What Duarte tried to say: Please learn how to embed images correctly on Blender Stack Exchange. If you want to add information to your question, please don't use the comments and use the edit link below your question to edit it.